# Django, spawn worker process on start generates django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, python-multiprocessing

Background:

I have an app that scrapes through our IT infrastructure resources (vCenter, storage, and backup entities) to pull things into a central inventory for quick reference.  Each collection spins up in its own thread, and I've taken measures to implement a producer/consumer setup to better scale for our resources.  What I've noticed is that when I have collections running from multiple types (Ex: vCenter and storage), the web interface chugs.  My thought is because I've got a ton of threads running from multiple sources and the GIL is causing everything to get queued up under one main thread.  So, I thought that I could have the main producer/consumer model run as processes instead of threads since they are fairly independent of each other.

What's wrong:

When I made the code switch from spinning up threads to processes, the worker process tries to load up the models that it should, but it fails because the sub process is separate, and the applications aren't loaded up. It throws `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

What I have found is since this spawned process doesn't inherit anything from the Django main process, it's trying to access the models without having anything started.  What I need is a method to spin these up but still have access to the Django ORM

What I need:

I need a way to spin up a process that can still interact with Django since it will be doing most of the heavy lifting.  My thought process is that if I can spin off the collections into their own process, it will keep everything snappy and won't interfere with the webserver speed.

To clarify, these processes are not getting spawned from a view, and are only communicating with each other via a multiprocessing `Queue`.  I'm not sending data back and forth between the spawned processes, but they are querying the database and writing data to it.

From what I found, the only thing that's remotely close to this is Celery, but in my brief research, that seems to be a bit more than I want to involve.  What it seems like I need to do is to have each of these spawned processes installed as an app in the Django settings, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Code samples:

Stacktrace:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Users\jfort\PycharmProjects\VmInventory\VMwareInventory\Processes\Vcenter.py", line 5, in <module>
    from VMwareInventory.VMwareRest.VMwareRest import RESTVCenter
  File "C:\Users\jfort\PycharmProjects\VmInventory\VMwareInventory\VMwareRest\VMwareRest.py", line 19, in <module>
    from VMwareInventory.models import *
  File "C:\Users\jfort\PycharmProjects\VmInventory\VMwareInventory\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .Base.cost import Cost
  File "C:\Users\jfort\PycharmProjects\VmInventory\VMwareInventory\models\Base\cost.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import BaseModel
  File "C:\Users\jfort\PycharmProjects\VmInventory\VMwareInventory\models\Base\base.py", line 4, in <module>
    class BaseModel(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from VMwareInventory.settings_local import environment
from VMwareInventory.threading.initial_settings import set_default_database_items


class VmwareinventoryConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'VMwareInventory'

    def ready(self):
        set_default_database_items()
        if environment == "prod":
            from .threading.scraping import TimerScrape
            TimerScrape()
```

threading\scraping.py (Where the TimerScrape() function lives):

```
# Python imports:
from threading import Thread, enumerate
from multiprocessing import Queue
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from time import sleep

# from queue import Queue

# Local imports:
from VMwareInventory.models import Vcenter, StorageSystem, BackupSystem, Setting, Platform, Application, Function, \
    Region, Site, Environment, TagsReport
from VMwareInventory.reports.tags_report import TagGenericReport
from VMwareInventory.reports.missing_tags_report import MissingTagsReport
from VMwareInventory.Processes.Backup import BackupWorker
from VMwareInventory.Processes.Storage import StorageWorker
from VMwareInventory.Processes.Vcenter import VcenterWorker

# Django imports:
from django.db import connection


class TimerScrape(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = "timerscrape_thread"
        self.vcenter_queue = Queue()
        self.vcenter_list = []
        self.storage_queue = Queue()
        self.storage_list = []
        self.backup_queue = Queue()
        self.backup_list = []
        self.vcenter_worker = 0
        self.storage_worker = 0
        self.backup_worker = 0
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        sleep(60)
        while True:
            vcenters = Vcenter.objects.all()
            netapps = StorageSystem.objects.all()
            rubriks = BackupSystem.objects.all()
            vcenter_threads = Setting.objects.get(name='vcenter_scraping_threads')
            storage_threads = Setting.objects.get(name='storage_scraping_threads')
            backup_threads = Setting.objects.get(name='backup_scraping_threads')
            wait_hours = int(Setting.objects.get(name='scrape_wait_time').value)
            connection.close()
            wait_seconds = wait_hours * 3600
            current_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

            # get list of current threading and their names
            threads = enumerate()
            # print(threads)
            thread_list = []
            worker_list = []
            for thread in threads:
                if thread.name == "vCenter_worker_thread":
                    worker_list.append(thread)
                elif thread.name == "storage_worker_thread":
                    worker_list.append(thread)
                elif thread.name == "backup_worker_thread":
                    worker_list.append(thread)
                else:
                    thread_list.append(thread.name)

            self.vcenter_worker = 0
            self.storage_worker = 0
            self.backup_worker = 0
            for thread in worker_list:
                if thread.name == "vCenter_worker_thread":
                    self.vcenter_worker += 1
                elif thread.name == "storage_worker_thread":
                    self.storage_worker += 1
                elif thread.name == "backup_worker_thread":
                    self.backup_worker += 1

            while self.vcenter_worker < int(vcenter_threads.value):
                VcenterWorker(self.vcenter_queue, self.vcenter_list)
                self.vcenter_worker += 1
            while self.storage_worker < int(storage_threads.value):
                StorageWorker(self.storage_queue, self.storage_list)
                self.storage_worker += 1
            while self.backup_worker < int(backup_threads.value):
                BackupWorker(self.backup_queue, self.backup_list)
                self.backup_worker += 1
```

Processes\Vcenter.py

```
# Python imports:
from multiprocessing import Process

# Local imports:
from VMwareInventory.VMwareRest.VMwareRest import RESTVCenter


class VcenterWorker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, vcenter_list):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.list = vcenter_list
        self.name = "vCenter_worker_process"
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            vcenter = self.queue.get()
            self.list.remove(vcenter)
            self.vcscrape(vcenter.name, vcenter.user, vcenter.password)
            self.queue.task_done()

    @staticmethod
    def vcscrape(name, user, pwd):
        vc_scrape = RESTVCenter(name, user, pwd)
        vc_scrape.join()
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after posting this directly on the Django forums, I was given some guidance.  I basically had to break these off as "standalone" Django processes in order to allow them access into the Django ORM.

I had to setup a settings, and run `django.setup()` in each of the processes and shift any models imports into code that would run after that execution.